# Combining regular expression validators into a custom validator (C#)

Tags: c#, validation, customvalidator

I have three regular expression validators which targets the same textbox but gives different error messages respectively.

How do I combine them in a custom validator to return different ErrorMessage?

```
public void PasswordValidate(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            Regex PasswordComplexity = new Regex(@"^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$");
            Regex ConsecutiveCharCheck = new Regex(@"^(?!.*(?:(.)\1{3,})).*$");
            Regex PasswordLiteralCheck = new Regex(@"^((?!(p|P)(a|A)(s|S)(s|S)(w|W)(o|O)(r|R)(d|D)).)*$");
```

Comment: What's the reason for "combining" them? Surely three separate validators for each case is perfectly appropriate?

Comment: Styling by design. Would prefer to display in single block rather than 3 seperate ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should keep them as the three separate validators. However, if you want to separate password validation from the remainder of the form's validation, then you might look into the [`ValidationGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) property for grouping their output.

**Edit:** Based on comments below, I believe the preferred solution was to set the `Display` property to Dynamic and keep the multiple RegularExpressionValidator's.

Comment: yeh.. I shouldn't seperate this one from the rest of the form. otherwise validationGroup will be the obvious solution.

Comment: I take it customValidators can't spit out different error messages based on 3 different regex? In which case I've to write more css to make it look right (whichever one fires together or seperately)

Comment: If you make the Display property as Dynamic does that not solve your problem with regard to visual spacing (you'll still need to ensure your regex patterns don't overlap)? Or perhaps a ValidationSummary control is appropriate for rolling together your validation messages?

Comment: @Brandon - it'll be tough to get the dynamic message part of a custom validation working if you want to try to support client-side validation (which a normal RegularExpressionValidator could give you).

Comment: I will use extra div and css to try make it look right (and not overlap) then.